# How can I show a dynamic component that has already been destroyed in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, angular8

I'm new with angular. I am creating a chat application that should work as follows.

There is a list of users and when you click on each one you must show a box with the messages of that user, this should allow each box to close. there everything is fine.

My problem is that when closing each box, when clicking on the corresponding user it is not shown again. It is probably due to the fact that the id of the user who was clicked is stored in array and it is validated that if that id is in the array does not show it, the issue is that I do this to prevent me from duplicating the box when it is already being displayed and I don't know how else to do it.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component,ViewChild,ViewContainerRef,ComponentFactoryResolver,ComponentRef,OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ConversacionComponent} from "./components/conversacion/conversacion.component";
import {ChatService} from "./services/chat.service";
import {Mensaje} from "./models/mensaje";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    providers:[ChatService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {

    /*Esto se usa para poder crear el componente de las ventanas de chat dinamicamente y que cada uno pueda eliminarse*/
    @ViewChild('componentsContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: false }) container: ViewContainerRef;
    private subs: Subscription[] = [];
    /****************/
    public id_usuario_destino:number;
    public personas:Array<any>;
    public id_persona:number;
    public mensajes:Mensaje[];
    public alreadyDone : number[];
    ngOnDestroy() {
        // unsubscribe from all on destroy
        this.subs.forEach(sub => sub.unsubscribe());

    }

    onClickAdd = (elemento) => {
        if(this.alreadyDone.findIndex(x => x === elemento.id) === -1)
        {
            this.alreadyDone.push(elemento.id);
            this.id_usuario_destino=elemento.id;
            this.id_persona=this.id_usuario_destino;
            this._chatService.getMessages(1,this.id_usuario_destino).subscribe(
                response=>{
                    if(response.mensajes){
                        this.mensajes=response.mensajes;
                        /*Este código es para crear las ventanas de chat dinamicas y que cada una pueda cerrarse*/
                        const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ConversacionComponent);
                        const component = this.container.createComponent(factory);
                        component.instance.destino=this.id_usuario_destino;
                        component.instance.numberCreated = this.container.length;
                        component.instance.men = this.mensajes;
                        // subscribe to component event to know when to delete
                        const selfDeleteSub = component.instance.deleteSelf
                            .pipe(tap(() => component.destroy()))
                            .subscribe();
                        // add subscription to array for clean up
                        this.subs.push(selfDeleteSub);
                        /*************************************************************************************/
                    }


                },
                error=>{
                    console.log(error);
                }
            );
        }



    }


    constructor( private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,private  _chatService:ChatService) {
        this.alreadyDone=[];
        this.personas=[
            {id:"2",
                nombre:"sergio"
            },
            {id:"3",
                nombre:"jhoyner"
            },
            {id:"4",
                nombre:"gerardo"
            },
            {id:"5",
                nombre:"fabrizio"
            }
        ]
    }



}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="sidenav">
  <ul *ngFor="let persona of personas">
    <li><a id="{{persona.id}}"(click)="onClickAdd($event.target)">{{persona.nombre}}</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>

<ng-template #componentsContainer></ng-template>
```

conversacion.component.html

```
<button (click)="deleteSelf.emit()" style="background-color: blue; color: white">close window</button>

<p>Number at time of creation: {{ numberCreated }}</p>
<div *ngFor="let message of men">
    {{message.contenido}}--{{message.fecha}}
</div>
<hr>
```

conversacion.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {Mensaje} from "../../models/mensaje";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-conversacion',
    templateUrl: './conversacion.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./conversacion.component.css']
})
export class ConversacionComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() deleteSelf = new EventEmitter<void>();
    @Input() numberCreated: number;
    @Input() men:Mensaje[];
    @Input() destino:number;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: could you do a stackBlitz demo of it please?

Comment: the code is there https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b161lt  ,but it is not working,I guess because I get the list of users from a service,above there is an image of the list of user and two box,if I close the box of sergio when I click on the user sergio that box is not shown

Comment: Could you see the project?If you want can write by email my friend, i need help because Im new with Angular

Comment: I can see the project but It is not working

Comment: do you have access to the chat?

Comment: Yes I think,Tell me what chat we can communicate

Comment: oh no you don't have access to it, the one of Stack overflow I mean

Comment: it says `The selector "app-root" did not match any elements` can't find a way to make it work

Comment: Sorry for my bad English,Do you mean https://chat.stackoverflow.com/ ? Because I can

Comment: I've picked [this one](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191442/angular-newbies)

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, I don´t hace access to that room,I only have 12 reputation and I need 20 :(. I can see but I can't write

Comment: please make the stackblitz example working then ping me ok? thanks in advance

Comment: OK thanks,tomorrow I will try to do it

Comment: see you then tommorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an input on to your component for the id and change your delete self emitter to emit a number, and use that to update your alreadyDone array.

conversacion.component.html

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {Mensaje} from "../../models/mensaje";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-conversacion',
    templateUrl: './conversacion.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./conversacion.component.css']
})
export class ConversacionComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() deleteSelf = new EventEmitter<number>();
    @Input() numberCreated: number;
    @Input() men:Mensaje[];
    @Input() destino:number;
    @Input() id: number;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }


}
```

Then change where you're looking at the deleteSelf emitter in app.component.ts to do something like this:

```
component.instance.id= elemento.id;
const selfDeleteSub = component.instance.deleteSelf
                            .pipe(tap(x => {
                                this.alreadyDone = this.alreadyDone.filter(done => done != x);
                                component.destroy();}))
                            .subscribe();
```

conversacion.component.html:

```
<button (click)="deleteSelf.emit(id)" style="background-color: blue; color: white">close window</button>

<p>Number at time of creation: {{ numberCreated }}</p>
<div *ngFor="let message of men">
    {{message.contenido}}--{{message.fecha}}
</div>
<hr>
```

Comment: thanks a lot .Your code worked perfectly.Could you explain to me what exactly the code you added in the constant "selfDeleteSub" does in app.component.ts?I don't understand what that constant does

Comment: When your conversacion component is being closed it is emitting a value with the deleteSelf output parameter.  Your selfDeleteSub is a observable that is listening for those value outputs.  What I did was changed the delete self emitter to output an int (the id of the component being closed) and in the parent when listening for those values I removed that id from the alreadyDone array since you want it to be able to be opened up again after it is closed.